# Чем проверить и удалить поврежденные .jpg файлы?

Tags: ubuntu

Есть директория с подпапками в ней. При загрузке картинок формата .jpg некоторые из них не докачались, при просмотре выдают ошибку.
Нужно как-то перебрать папки и удалить эти поврежденные картинки.

Есть ли способы, как избежать перебора вручную?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Установить imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) и его инструментом [identify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) пробежаться по каждому из файлов.

Не пробовал, но вероятно, у битых, например, размер не будет определяться, или что-то ещё — надо пробовать.

Comment: Попробовал так:
   
    find tvr/tm -name "*.jpg" -exec identify -verbose {} {} \;

Если файл поврежден, пишет

    identify.im6: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x75 0x6e `tvr/tm/pic.jpg' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/316.

Можно ли как-то записать ссылки на поврежденные файлы? Куда нибудь в .txt файл, чтобы перезаписать их?
Ну или удалить совсем.

Comment: Вообще странно, что файл *начинается* с плохой секвенции. Недокачанные я бы ожидал увидеть с отрезанным концом, но целым началом.

Перепроверил: у искусственно недокачанного (только первые 30к из 104k), с `-verbose` пишет:

> identify: Premature end of JPEG file `thumb_bad.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/351.
> identify: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment `thumb_bad.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/351.

Comment: identify пишет ошибки в stderr. Я бы сделал скрипт типа id.sh:

    #/bin/bash
    identify -verbose -format "%f\\n" "$1"  2>>/tmp/list_of_bad_pics.txt

И запустил `find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec ./id.sh {} \;`, после чего в файле было бы по две строки на кадый плохой файл. И дальше возился с grep'ами. Наверняка можно эффективнее сделать.

Comment: Попробовал, пишет 

....id.sh': Отказано в доступе

Comment: `chmod 755 id.sh` не поможет?